# Solve the following recurrence $f(n) = 2^n f(n - 1) + 2^n$ given $f(0)=1$.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Solve the recurrence $f(n) = 2^n f(n - 1) + 2^n$ given $f(0)=1$.

The pattern I can come up with is

$2^{2n-1} f(n - 2) + 2^{3n-1}$

$2^{3n-3} f(n - 3) + 2^{6n-4}$

$2^{4n-6} f(n - 4) + 2^{10n-10}$

How do I solve the recurrence relation from this pattern? Thanks.

Comment: You already have a recurrence relation. Presumably you want to _solve_ the recurrence.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Then see marty cohen's answer.

Comment: Exponential generating functions require you to solve the differential equation $g'(x) = \frac{1}{2} g(2x) + \frac{1}{2} e^{2x}$; then the $n$th coefficient of $x$ in $g(x)$ is $\frac{f(n)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$f(n) = 2^n f(n - 1) + 2^n
$.

Since
$\sum_{k=1}^n k
= n(n+1)/2
$,
divide the recurrence by
$2^{ n(n+1)/2}$.
It becomes
$\dfrac{f(n)}{2^{ n(n+1)/2}} 
=  \dfrac{f(n - 1)}{2^{ n(n+1)/2-n}} + \dfrac1{{2^{ n(n+1)/2-n}}}
=  \dfrac{f(n - 1)}{2^{ n(n-1)/2}} + \dfrac1{{2^{ n(n-1)/2}}}
$.

Now,
let
$g(n)
=\dfrac{f(n)}{2^{ n(n+1)/2}} 
$.
Then
$g(n-1)
=\dfrac{f(n-1)}{2^{ (n-1)n/2}} 
$
so the recurrence becomes
$g(n)
=  g(n-1) + \dfrac1{{2^{ n(n-1)/2}}}
$,
or
$g(n)-  g(n-1) 
= \dfrac1{{2^{ n(n-1)/2}}}
$.

Summing,
$g(n)-g(0)
=\sum_{k=1}^n (g(k_)-g(k-1))
=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{{2^{ k(k-1)/2}}}
$,
or
$\dfrac{f(n)}{2^{ n(n+1)/2}} -f(0)
=\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{{2^{ k(k-1)/2}}}
$
or
$f(n)
=2^{ n(n+1)/2}+2^{ n(n+1)/2}\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac1{{2^{ k(k-1)/2}}}
$.

Solving this involves summing
$\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac1{{2^{ n(n-1)/2}}}
$.

I don't know how to sum this,
so I'll leave it here.

---

(added later)

Following up on my thought
that this looked
like a theta function,
I looked in good old
Whittaker and Watson.
In section 21.11,
page 464,
I find this 
(with a script theta that I don't know
how to enter):

$\theta_2(z, q)
=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{(n+1/2)^2}\cos((2n+1)z)
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\theta_2(0, q)
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{(n+1/2)^2}\\
&=2q^{1/4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n^2+n}\\
\text{so}\\
\theta_2(0, r^{1/2})
&=2r^{1/8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} r^{(n^2+n)/2}
\qquad q = r^{1/2}\\
\text{so}\\
\theta_2(0, (1/2)^{1/2})
&=2(1/2)^{1/8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^{(n^2+n)/2}\\
&=2^{7/8}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/2)^{(n^2+n)/2}
\qquad r = 1/2\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{2^{(n^2+n)/2}}
=2^{-7/8}\theta_2(0, (1/2)^{1/2})
$.